# When did Google Play start crawling apps daily and can it be turned off

Tags: android

I can't find any information to indicate that this should be happening or any one else talking about.
Since my most recent upload to Google Play, I've been getting devices running my app from America every day.
I know it is Google bots because the app hasn't been released to anyone yet

Has this always been happening or is it a new thing?
How do I turn it off?
Are these likely to trigger install events on tracking SDK's?

This would mean the analytics in my other app is way off because, due to library limitations (React native firebase 5 did not allow tracking to be turned off in test and they decided to fix it in 6 instead...) we were happy to assume that analytics on days I deployed would be off, but not every day after that.

This would have generated a load of non converting users.

Comment: I heard about that, these bots automatically test your app after deploy.